# Using Excel to read and write data to a RESTful API

Tags: json, excel, rest

I have data exposed by [JSON RESTful API](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restquicktips.html) with full CRUD operations.  I want to be able to load a set of records into Excel. Then I want to edit/add/remove the rows. Then I want to hit the "Refresh" button in Excel to push all the modifications back to the RESTful API.

How can I do this?  Is there an add-in for Excel to do this? I see that Excel supports several "data connection" protocols,

[image: excel data tab]

The "Other Sources" has Wizards for OLEDB and ODBC. Is it reasonable to write a two-way adapter for one of those protocols that will read/write the REST api?

If this is too hard I suppose I could ditch Excel and use a web-based table editor, like [jtable](http://www.jtable.org/), or [jqgrid](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/table-editor). Any advice appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a web developer, but I think that the XMLHTTP object in the Microsoft XML Services library is in the direction that you are asking.

Comment: You could write a two-way adapter, but it would be considerable work.  YOu could use a web based editor, but that would also be a lot of work.  What scripting languages do you know.

Comment: @TobyAllen I know C# and angular JS. I don't know VBA, but I could learn it. I starting to think I have two options. Write my own VBA script in Excel to pull/push data to an XML-based .Net service (which I would have to write)... or Drop Excel, and just make a web app using angular + ui-grid.  probably the latter will be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: No probably about it